# SQL find in other field data and update another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have troubles with doing such sql query for mysql db:
I need to update field A in my db, but also i have B field, which contains much data, for example:

```
ASIAN HORSE 70з рус 600A (261x175x220)
```

or

```
Бэрен polar 55/59з (555112) 480A (242x175x190)
```

i must fetch 70з and set it in field A, and 55/59з same (but for another record).

But how can i search in B field something what end's with `з` but is word (not all data as % before `з`)

I know, that it could sound like homework... but i real don't know ho to select only word with some end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL function [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) can be used to select pieces of a string delimited by something. For example this picks out the third "word" from MyColumn:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(MyColumn, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) from MyTable
```

(`70з` is the third "word" in `ASIAN HORSE 70з рус 600A (261x175x220)`.)

**Update** If instead of the third word you are looking for the "word" that ends with 'з', you can use:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(MyColumn, 'з', 1), ' ', -1) from MyTable
```

This will consider 'з' as the delimiter though, and removes it from the result. You can add it back with concat:

```
select concat(substring_index(substring_index(MyColumn, 'з', 1), ' ', -1), 'з') from MyTable
```

Comment: but what, when it is not third? it could be third-fifth

Comment: Then use `'з'` in the inner `substring_index` instead of a space, or does that vary as well? Then concatenate `'з'` to the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse the field so the third value always goes into a particular field, then you have a hard problem and probably want to create a user-defined function.

However, if you just want to see if 70з is present and set another field, then this should work:

```
update t
    set B = '70з'
    where A like '% 70з' or A like '% 70з %' or A like '70з %' or A = '70з'
```

This uses spaces to define the word boundaries and considers whether the string is at the beginning, in the middle, at the end, or the entire value in A.

Comment: also it is not only 70з... it could be other values... also not on the third position... but field must contain for example 70з